# How to make image always on top

Tags: javascript, html, css

i made card class and put image on it. After it, added circle and circle fills all the card when hover effect triggered. But after i trigger hover effect the image cuts on top side. How to disable it? I want to make it visible after hover effect same as begginnig.

Here is my code. How to change it to visible?
tried some overflow or clip elements but it didnt work at all.

```css
body {
    background: #f2f4f8;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    height: 100vh;
    font-family: "Open Sans";
  }
  
  .education {
    --bg-color: #FD4556;
    --bg-color-light: #ffeeba;
    --text-color-hover: white;
    --box-shadow-color: #FD4556;
  }
  
  .credentialing {
    --bg-color: #B8F9D3;
    --bg-color-light: #e2fced;
    --text-color-hover: #4C5656;
    --box-shadow-color: rgba(184, 249, 211, 0.48);
  }
  
  .wallet {
    --bg-color: #CEB2FC;
    --bg-color-light: #F0E7FF;
    --text-color-hover: #fff;
    --box-shadow-color: rgba(206, 178, 252, 0.48);
  }
  
  .human-resources {
    --bg-color: #DCE9FF;
    --bg-color-light: #f1f7ff;
    --text-color-hover: #4C5656;
    --box-shadow-color: rgba(220, 233, 255, 0.48);
  }
  
  .card {
    width: 200px;
    height: 310px;
    background: #fff;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    box-shadow: 0 14px 26px rgba(0,0,0,0.04);
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 20px;
    
  }
  
  .card:hover {
    transform: translateY(-5px) scale(1.005) translateZ(0);
    box-shadow: 0 24px 36px rgba(0,0,0,0.11),
      0 24px 46px var(--box-shadow-color);
  }
  
  .card:hover .overlay {
    transform: scale(4) translateZ(0);
  }
  
  .card:hover .circle {
    border-color: var(--bg-color-light);
    background: var(--bg-color);
  }
  
  .card:hover .circle:after {
    background: var(--bg-color-light);
  }
  
  .card:hover p {
    color: var(--text-color-hover);
  }
  
  .card:active {
    transform: scale(1) translateZ(0);
    box-shadow: 0 15px 24px rgba(0,0,0,0.11),
      0 15px 24px var(--box-shadow-color);
  }
  
  .card p {
    font-size: 28px;
    color: #4C5656;
    margin-top: 60px;
    padding-top: 30px;
    z-index: 1000;
    transition: color 0.3s ease-out;
  }
  
  .circle {
    margin-bottom: -22px;
    width: 131px;
    height: 131px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #fff;
    border: 2px solid var(--bg-color);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  }
  
  .circle:after {
    content: "";
    width: 118px;
    height: 118px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    background: var(--bg-color);
    border-radius: 50%;
    top: 7px;
    left: 7px;
    transition: opacity 0.3s ease-out;
  }
  
  .circle svg {
    z-index: 10000;
    transform: translateZ(0);
  }
  
  .overlay {
    width: 118px;
    position: absolute; 
    height: 118px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: var(--bg-color);
    top: 36px;
    left: 50px;
    z-index: 0;
    transition: transform 0.3s ease-out;
  }
```

```html
<body>

<a href="#" class="card education">
     <div class="overlay"></div>
  <div class="circle">
    <img class="card-image" src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/998657954536489042/1106584776946745424/Raze_-_Full_body.png" style="
    height: 16em;
    z-index: 2000;
    position: fixed;
">
  </div>
  <p>VALORANT
  </p>
</a>
```

Comment: It gets cropped because of the `overflow: hidden;`

Comment: @Developer yes. When hover effect runs the image cuts off on top side. I want to stop it and make image visible all time like before hover effect.

Comment: @jsnewbie In  the answer code, it is not cutting and also showing hover effect. I thought it would be more good. Because static image was not looking good. So, I think, while keeping the image moving without cutting the image is more good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
body {
    background: #f2f4f8;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    height: 100vh;
    font-family: "Open Sans";
  }
  
  .education {
    --bg-color: #FD4556;
    --bg-color-light: #ffeeba;
    --text-color-hover: white;
    --box-shadow-color: #FD4556;
  }
  
  .credentialing {
    --bg-color: #B8F9D3;
    --bg-color-light: #e2fced;
    --text-color-hover: #4C5656;
    --box-shadow-color: rgba(184, 249, 211, 0.48);
  }
  
  .wallet {
    --bg-color: #CEB2FC;
    --bg-color-light: #F0E7FF;
    --text-color-hover: #fff;
    --box-shadow-color: rgba(206, 178, 252, 0.48);
  }
  
  .human-resources {
    --bg-color: #DCE9FF;
    --bg-color-light: #f1f7ff;
    --text-color-hover: #4C5656;
    --box-shadow-color: rgba(220, 233, 255, 0.48);
  }
  
  .card {
    width: 200px;
    height: 310px;
    background: #fff;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    box-shadow: 0 14px 26px rgba(0,0,0,0.04);
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 20px;
  }
  
  .card:hover {
    transform: translateY(-5px) scale(1.005) translateZ(0);
    box-shadow: 0 24px 36px rgba(0,0,0,0.11),
      0 24px 46px var(--box-shadow-color);
  }
  
  .card:hover .overlay {
    transform: scale(4) translateZ(0);
  }
  
  .card:hover .circle {
    border-color: var(--bg-color-light);
    background: var(--bg-color);
  }
  
  .card:hover .circle:after {
    background: var(--bg-color-light);
  }
  
  .card:hover p {
    color: var(--text-color-hover);
  }
  
  .card:active {
    transform: scale(1) translateZ(0);
    box-shadow: 0 15px 24px rgba(0,0,0,0.11),
      0 15px 24px var(--box-shadow-color);
  }
  
  .card p {
    font-size: 28px;
    color: #4C5656;
    margin-top: 60px;
    padding-top: 30px;
    z-index: 1000;
    transition: color 0.3s ease-out;
  }
  
  .circle {
    margin-bottom: -22px;
    width: 131px;
    height: 131px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #fff;
    border: 2px solid var(--bg-color);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  }
  
  .circle:after {
    content: "";
    width: 118px;
    height: 118px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    background: var(--bg-color);
    border-radius: 50%;
    top: 7px;
    left: 7px;
    transition: opacity 0.3s ease-out;
  }
  
  .circle svg {
    z-index: 10000;
    transform: translateZ(0);
  }
  
  .overlay {
    width: 118px;
    position: absolute; 
    height: 118px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: var(--bg-color);
    top: 36px;
    left: 50px;
    z-index: 0;
    transition: transform 0.3s ease-out;
  }
  
  .container {
    position: relative;
  }
  
  .card-image {
    position: absolute;
    top: -36px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    pointer-events: none;
  }
```

```html
<body>

<span class="container">
<a href="#" class="card education">
     <div class="overlay"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <p>VALORANT</p>
</a>
<img class="card-image" src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/998657954536489042/1106584776946745424/Raze_-_Full_body.png" style="
    height: 16em;
">
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say, give **position: absolute to img**, it will give best results. It will show the character moving with hover without cutting image.

With **top property on img**, you can adjust the **image position**. Here is the updated code:-

```css
body {
    background: #f2f4f8;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    height: 100vh;
    font-family: "Open Sans";
  }
  
  .education {
    --bg-color: #FD4556;
    --bg-color-light: #ffeeba;
    --text-color-hover: white;
    --box-shadow-color: #FD4556;
  }
  
  .credentialing {
    --bg-color: #B8F9D3;
    --bg-color-light: #e2fced;
    --text-color-hover: #4C5656;
    --box-shadow-color: rgba(184, 249, 211, 0.48);
  }
  
  .wallet {
    --bg-color: #CEB2FC;
    --bg-color-light: #F0E7FF;
    --text-color-hover: #fff;
    --box-shadow-color: rgba(206, 178, 252, 0.48);
  }
  
  .human-resources {
    --bg-color: #DCE9FF;
    --bg-color-light: #f1f7ff;
    --text-color-hover: #4C5656;
    --box-shadow-color: rgba(220, 233, 255, 0.48);
  }
  
  .card {
    width: 200px;
    height: 310px;
    background: #fff;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    box-shadow: 0 14px 26px rgba(0,0,0,0.04);
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 20px;
    
  }
  
  .card:hover {
    transform: translateY(-5px) scale(1.005) translateZ(0);
    box-shadow: 0 24px 36px rgba(0,0,0,0.11),
      0 24px 46px var(--box-shadow-color);
  }
  
  .card:hover .overlay {
    transform: scale(4) translateZ(0);
  }
  
  .card:hover .circle {
    border-color: var(--bg-color-light);
    background: var(--bg-color);
  }
  
  .card:hover .circle:after {
    background: var(--bg-color-light);
  }
  
  .card:hover p {
    color: var(--text-color-hover);
  }
  

  
  .card:active {
    transform: scale(1) translateZ(0);
    box-shadow: 0 15px 24px rgba(0,0,0,0.11),
      0 15px 24px var(--box-shadow-color);
  }
  
  .card p {
    font-size: 28px;
    color: #4C5656;
    margin-top: 60px;
    padding-top: 30px;
    z-index: 1000;
    transition: color 0.3s ease-out;
  }
  
  .circle {
    margin-bottom: -22px;
    width: 131px;
    height: 131px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #fff;
    border: 2px solid var(--bg-color);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  }
  
  .circle:after {
    content: "";
    width: 118px;
    height: 118px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    background: var(--bg-color);
    border-radius: 50%;
    top: 7px;
    left: 7px;
    transition: opacity 0.3s ease-out;
  }
  
  .circle svg {
    z-index: 10000;
    transform: translateZ(0);
  }
  
  .overlay {
    width: 118px;
    position: absolute; 
    height: 118px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: var(--bg-color);
    top: 36px;
    left: 50px;
    z-index: 0;
    transition: transform 0.3s ease-out;
  }
```

```html
<body>
<a href="#" class="card education">
     <div class="overlay"></div>
  <div class="circle">
    <img class="card-image" src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/998657954536489042/1106584776946745424/Raze_-_Full_body.png" style="
    height: 16em;
    z-index: 2000;
    position: absolute;
    top: -30px;
">
  </div>
  <p>VALORANT
  </p>
</a>

</body>
```